# How is this an example of a preposition connecting a noun or a pronoun to another clause?

Tags: prepositions

In this grammar book I am working through, prepositions are defined as words that connect certain nouns and pronouns (AKA objects of prepositions) to clauses. However, in the following sentence, I am not sure how this is the case:

> The man in the blue shirt stood in front of the store.

I understand that the object of the preposition is shirt, but how come it is connected to "The man" if "The man" is clearly not a clause? Similarly, how does the other object of the preposition (store) connect to "The man" (since it's not a clause)?

Comment: Prepositions can also connect nouns to nouns. Are you sure that your grammar book doesn't allow for this possibility? Maybe a noun counts as a noun clause by itself.

Comment: There are a lot of poor grammar books out there. Prepositions are defined in English usually by giving a list of the most common ones, and optionally noting that they tend to fade between preposition, adverb, and conjunction usages. As @PeterShor points out, there are lots of other uses for prepositions than what you quoted. Typically prepositional phrases modify nouns, verbs, verb phrases, and clauses, which leaves a lot of room for them.

Comment: I agree with JL. In your example the preposition phrase "in the blue shirt" modifies the noun "man" to give the larger noun phrase "the man in the blue shirt".

Answer (score 1):

Prepositional phrases that look like they don't connect nouns to clauses can be interpreted such that there's an assumed *that is* or *which is* which introduces a relative clause.

> The man [that is] in the blue shirt stood in front of the store.

> The books [that are] on the shelf are the ones I wanted.